# Assignment not allowed in while expression?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop

In Java we can usually perform an assignment within the `while` condition. However Kotlin complains about it. So the following code does not compile:

```
val br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(
        conn.inputStream))

var output: String
println("Output from Server .... \n")
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) { // <--- error here: Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context
    println(output)
}
```

According to this other [thread](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/assignment-not-allow-in-while-expression/339/6), this seems the best solution:

```
val reader = BufferedReader(reader)
var line: String? = null;
while ({ line = reader.readLine(); line }() != null) { // <--- The IDE asks me to replace this line for while(true), what the...?
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

But is it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, the best way, IMO, would be

```
val reader = BufferedReader(reader)
reader.lineSequence().forEach {
    println(it)
}
```

And if you want to make sure the reader is properly closed (as you would with a try-with-resources statement in Java), you can use

```
BufferedReader(reader).use { r ->
    r.lineSequence().forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25):

And here is a short Kotlin-style general [solution](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/assignment-not-allow-in-while-expression/339/19) by Roman Elizarov:

```
while (true) {
    val line = reader.readLine() ?: break
    println(line);
}
```

Here `break` has [Nothing](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#the-nothing-type) type that also helps to promote type inference for the `line` as non-nullable string.

Answer (score 13):

Here is the shortest solution [powered](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/for-each-line.html) by stdlib that also safely closes the reader:

```
reader.forEachLine {
    println(it)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In cases you just want to replace `while ((x = y.someFunction()) != null)` you may use the following instead:

```
generateSequence { y.someFunction() }
          .forEach { x -> /* what you did in your while */ }
```

[`generateSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html) will extract you all the values one by one until the first `null` is reached. You may replace the [`.forEach`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/for-each.html) with a [`reduce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/reduce.html) or [`fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/fold.html) (or anything else that seems appropriate ;-)) if you want to keep the last value or sum up the values to something else.

For your specific use case however you may just use what [JB Nizet in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41537792/6202869) has shown or use [`useLines`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/use-lines.html#uselines):

```
reader.useLines {
  it.forEach(::println)
}
```

[`.forEachLine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/for-each-line.html) is probably the next best short-hand solution to that specific `readLine`-problem (already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43557686/6202869)) if you know you just want to read all lines and then stop.

Answer (score 2):

I found that these days IntelliJ converts your Java code into the following kotlin code:

```kotlin
val br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(
        conn.inputStream))

var output: String
while (br.readLine().also { output = it } != null) {
    println(output)
}
```

This is still confusing but it's quite readable. It uses the fact that `also` returns the receiver instance (the result of `br.readLine()` here).

Answer (score -1):

(This Example for while loop ) Hope this example will help you..

Change from

while ((c = `is`.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            sb.append(String(buffer, 0, c, Charset.forName(UTF8)))
}

to

while ({c = `is`.read(buffer);c}() > 0) {
            sb.append(String(buffer, 0, c, Charset.forName(UTF8)))
}