# connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have simple client and server socket application connecting each other based on this [code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/establishing-the-two-way-communication-between-server-and-client-in-java/). In the beginning i can send hello message from client to server and server to client but my problem is to send next message when i try to send message onclick it's returning `java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.16 (port 5000) from /:: (port 57650): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)`

Both applications are running in same emulator

Where is my problem?

Here is my server : My server socket is in Service.I execute it when service starts

```
class SocketService: Service() {

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    thread { ClientHandler().run() }
    return START_STICKY
}

internal inner class ClientHandler() : Runnable{
    override fun run() {
        val server = ServerSocket(5000)
        val client = server.accept()
        var reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()))
        var writer = PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream())
        try {
            writer.write("hello from server" + "\n")
            writer.flush()


            receiveString = reader.readLine()

        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Timber.e("$ex")
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my client

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    Timber.plant(FileLog(applicationContext))

   thread { ThreadopenPort("hello").run() }
}


fun sendMessage(view:View){
    try {
        val message = "message on button click"

        thread { ThreadopenPort(message).run() }
    }catch (ex:Exception){

        Timber.i(messageLog)
    }
}

internal inner class ThreadopenPort(private val message: String) : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        var socket: Socket
        try {
            socket = Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT)
            output = PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream())
            input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))
            if (i == 0) {
                output!!.write("hello from client" + "\n")
                output!!.flush()
                rMessage = input!!.readLine()

                run {
                    runOnUiThread(Runnable {
                        textView.text = textView.text.toString() + "server: $rMessage\n"

                    })
                }

                input!!.close()
                output!!.close()
                socket.close()
            }

            if (input!!.readLine() != null){
                output!!.write(message+ "\n")
                output!!.flush()
                rMessage = input!!.readLine()

                run {
                    runOnUiThread(Runnable {
                        textView.text = textView.text.toString() + "server: $rMessage\n"

                    })
                }

                input!!.close()
                output!!.close()
                socket.close()
            }

            Timber.i("Message received from Payment Service at $formatted message: ${rMessage}")


        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code of your client is a mess and impossible. The client tries to read a line after it closed the socket. That will not go of course. Further there is twice "hello from client" in your code. Please repair that first.

Comment: @blackapps First hello from client is when program start second one is on button click , also i thought when i send first hello i close socket then open and close every onclick

Comment: @blackapps by the way when i delete close function i got  same error or 'Connection reset' error

Comment: I see no button click and you are not explaining about  if (i == 0). But you create a new client socket eerytime. Open and close on every click is ok. But dont use an i. You can just put another message at creating the thread. Difficult code in this way.

Comment: @blackapps if(i==0) is just for oncreate i know its dirty code but for now it’s ok. The other message can be hello1 doesn’t matter can you suggest me solution?

Comment: Sorry. I do not manage what you call 'your dirty code'. Takes too much time.

Comment: @blackapps i didnt want to manage my code i just want suggession for solution if(i==0) is not important here

Comment: *Where is my problem?* - Probably not in your code.  Connection refused usually means that nothing was listening for the connection request on the IP / port that the connection request reached.  There can be lots of root causes for this.